# How to inset an image on top of the magnified portion in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy, zooming

I want to magnify an image in LaTeX such that the original image is visible inside the zoomed portion. If I use the spy library then zoomed portion is always on top. I could not find how the magnified portion can go below the main image. Please see the following minimal example. I want the left image (in the output PDF) on top of the right image (zoomed image). In other words, I want the main image as an inset at bottom right part of the zoomed portion with a red rectangle showing which area is zoomed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  [spy using outlines={rectangle,red,magnification=7,size= 8 cm}]   
  \node   {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \spy on (-1,0) in node at (4.5,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Much simpler solution due to Paul Gaborit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle,red,magnification=7,size= 8 cm}]   
  \node   {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \spy[on background layer,
  spy connection path={  \draw (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \draw[red] (tikzspyonnode.south west) rectangle (tikzspyonnode.north east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}}] on (-1,0) in node at (4.5,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD AND UGLIER SOLUTION**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle,red,magnification=7,size= 8 cm}]   
  \node (x)  {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \spy[spy connection path={\draw (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);
  \path coordinate (bl) at (tikzspyonnode.south west);
  \path coordinate (tr) at (tikzspyonnode.north east);}] on (-1,0) in node at (4.5,3);
 \end{scope}  
 \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \node (y) at (x) {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \draw[red] (bl) rectangle (tr);
 \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why did I post all these solutions? Simply because "more obvious" solutions do not seem to work. For instance,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle,red,magnification=7,size= 8 cm}]   
  \node (x)  {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \spy on (-1,0) in node at (4.5,3);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields

[image]

i.e., the zoomed in picture is *not* on the background, and even more surprisingly

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={rectangle,red,magnification=7,size= 8 cm}]   
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \node (x)  {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \spy on (-1,0) in node at (4.5,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks, marmot. It is helpful! Can you please also add some details on how to do the calculation for the small red 'rectangle' coordinates that you draw because I want to change 'spy on' point.

Comment: @Hemant I made an update. You do no longer have to compute the box coordinates by hand.

Comment: @marmot In `tikzlibraryspy.code.tex`, the `spy scope` key always copies the `\tikz@lib@spy@collection` _at the end_ of the scope.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I see. Thanks! I guess that you can post a simpler answer.

Comment: Thanks, @marmot, the updated answer is helpful. Though, I could not make this work with subfigure settings. Probably I should ask a separate question on it.

Comment: @Hemant There is no reason why this won't work in a subfigure. So most likely there is something else which causes the issue, in which case this would make it a separate question.

Comment: @marmot, Yes it worked with subfigures. Thanks!

Comment: how can we do it with subfigures?
Also, how do we post a caption for such individual subfigures that have insets?