# Add arrow and words on a magnified pic using TikZ spy

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I want to add some arrows and words on a magnifying pic. Add A, B, and C on the magnifying pic. Could anybody help me fix this problem? Thanks[image]

```
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4,size=2.5cm, connect spies}]
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,1.5);
    \coordinate (B) at (6,1.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (D) at (6,1);
    \coordinate (E) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (G) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate (H) at (6,-1);
    \coordinate (I) at (2,-1.5);
    \coordinate (J) at (6,-1.5);
    %Upper 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/1.5/K, 4.1/1.5/L, 3.9/1/M, 4.1/1/N,3.8/1.5/O, 3.8/1.3/P, 3.9/1.3/Q,  4.1/1.1/R, 4.2/1.1/S, 4.2/1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %Lower 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/-1.5/K, 4.1/-1.5/L, 3.9/-1/M, 4.1/-1/N, 3.8/-1.5/O, 3.8/-1.3/P, 3.9/-1.3/Q,  4.1/-1.1/R, 4.2/-1.1/S, 4.2/-1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %The left figure
    \draw [->] (-0.3,0.7) arc [start angle=150, end angle=30, radius=10pt];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1cm];
    \foreach \x / \y in         {0/30,10/40,20/50,30/60,40/70,50/80,60/90,70/100,80/110,90/120,100/130,110/140,120/150,130/160,140/170,150/180,160/190,170/200,180/210,190/220,200/230,210/240,220/250,230/260,240/270,250/280,260/290,270/300,280/310,290/320,300/330,310/340,320/350,330/360,340/10,350/20}
    {\draw (\x:1) -- (\y:1.5);}
    %The right figure
    \draw (A)--(B);
    \draw (C)--(D);
    \draw (G)--(H);
    \draw (I)--(J);
    \draw (C) cos (1.86,0.5) sin (E);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines] (E) cos (2.14,-0.5) sin(G) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (E);
    %\draw (E) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (G);
    \draw (F) cos (6.14,-0.5) sin(H);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines](D) cos (6.14,0.5) sin (F) cos (5.86,0.5) sin (D);
    \draw [style=dashed] (-2,0)--(6.5,0) (0,2)--(0,-2);
    %located zoomed figure
    \spy [red] on (4,1.25) in node [spy] at (8,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. To make sure the arrows stay on top of the spied area I've used the `backgrounds` library. Made arrow `B` green to demonstrate it is indeed on top.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,spy,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4,size=2.5cm, connect spies}]
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,1.5);
    \coordinate (B) at (6,1.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (D) at (6,1);
    \coordinate (E) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (G) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate (H) at (6,-1);
    \coordinate (I) at (2,-1.5);
    \coordinate (J) at (6,-1.5);
    %Upper 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/1.5/K, 4.1/1.5/L, 3.9/1/M, 4.1/1/N,3.8/1.5/O, 3.8/1.3/P, 3.9/1.3/Q,  4.1/1.1/R, 4.2/1.1/S, 4.2/1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %Lower 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/-1.5/K, 4.1/-1.5/L, 3.9/-1/M, 4.1/-1/N, 3.8/-1.5/O, 3.8/-1.3/P, 3.9/-1.3/Q,  4.1/-1.1/R, 4.2/-1.1/S, 4.2/-1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %The left figure
    \draw [->] (-0.3,0.7) arc [start angle=150, end angle=30, radius=10pt];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1cm];
    \foreach \x / \y in         {0/30,10/40,20/50,30/60,40/70,50/80,60/90,70/100,80/110,90/120,100/130,110/140,120/150,130/160,140/170,150/180,160/190,170/200,180/210,190/220,200/230,210/240,220/250,230/260,240/270,250/280,260/290,270/300,280/310,290/320,300/330,310/340,320/350,330/360,340/10,350/20}
    {\draw (\x:1) -- (\y:1.5);}
    %The right figure
    \draw (A)--(B);
    \draw (C)--(D);
    \draw (G)--(H);
    \draw (I)--(J);
    \draw (C) cos (1.86,0.5) sin (E);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines] (E) cos (2.14,-0.5) sin(G) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (E);
    %\draw (E) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (G);
    \draw (F) cos (6.14,-0.5) sin(H);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines](D) cos (6.14,0.5) sin (F) cos (5.86,0.5) sin (D);
    \draw [style=dashed] (-2,0)--(6.5,0) (0,2)--(0,-2);
    %located zoomed figure
    \coordinate (zoomLoc) at (8,0);
    \spy [red] on (4,1.25) in node at (zoomLoc);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \draw [thick,<-] ([xshift=0.6cm,yshift=-0.3cm]zoomLoc)--++(-60:0.8cm)--++(0:0.7cm) node [right] {C};
    \draw [thick,<-] ([xshift=-0.6cm,yshift=0.5cm]zoomLoc)--++(70:1.2cm)--++(0:1.8cm) node [right] {A};
    \draw [green,thick,<-] ([xshift=0.3cm]zoomLoc)--++(70:1.2cm)--++(0:0.9cm) node [text=black,right] {B};
    \end{pgfonlayer}{foreground}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is my first time I know pgflayer. I am learning pgflayer from the pgfmannual. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer that is based on [this older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426272/121799) and conceptionally very similar to [Milo's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445684/121799). The slight advantage is that this answer comes with a local coordinate system for the zoomed part, which may make it more straightforward to place the annotations. In particular, if you ever decide to move the zoomed in stuff around and/or change the zoom factor, the annotations will adjust. Milos approach is also fine with moving the zoomed stuff around. I also use outlined arrows for the sake of a better visibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,spy,backgrounds,calc,arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every spy on node/.append style={alias=zoom}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,scale=1,spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4,size=2.5cm, connect spies}]
    \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A) at (2,1.5);
    \coordinate (B) at (6,1.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (2,1);
    \coordinate (D) at (6,1);
    \coordinate (E) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (F) at (6,0);
    \coordinate (G) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate (H) at (6,-1);
    \coordinate (I) at (2,-1.5);
    \coordinate (J) at (6,-1.5);
    %Upper 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/1.5/K, 4.1/1.5/L, 3.9/1/M, 4.1/1/N,3.8/1.5/O, 3.8/1.3/P, 3.9/1.3/Q,  4.1/1.1/R, 4.2/1.1/S, 4.2/1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %Lower 
    \foreach \x / \y / \z in {3.9/-1.5/K, 4.1/-1.5/L, 3.9/-1/M, 4.1/-1/N, 3.8/-1.5/O, 3.8/-1.3/P, 3.9/-1.3/Q,  4.1/-1.1/R, 4.2/-1.1/S, 4.2/-1.5/T}
    {\coordinate (\z) at (\x, \y);}
    \filldraw  (K)--(M)--(N)--(L)--(K);
    \draw (O)--(P)--(Q);
    \draw (R)--(S)--(T);
    %The left figure
    \draw [->] (-0.3,0.7) arc [start angle=150, end angle=30, radius=10pt];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \draw (center) circle [radius=1cm];
    \foreach \x / \y in         {0/30,10/40,20/50,30/60,40/70,50/80,60/90,70/100,80/110,90/120,100/130,110/140,120/150,130/160,140/170,150/180,160/190,170/200,180/210,190/220,200/230,210/240,220/250,230/260,240/270,250/280,260/290,270/300,280/310,290/320,300/330,310/340,320/350,330/360,340/10,350/20}
    {\draw (\x:1) -- (\y:1.5);}
    %The right figure
    \draw (A)--(B);
    \draw (C)--(D);
    \draw (G)--(H);
    \draw (I)--(J);
    \draw (C) cos (1.86,0.5) sin (E);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines] (E) cos (2.14,-0.5) sin(G) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (E);
    %\draw (E) cos (1.86,-0.5) sin (G);
    \draw (F) cos (6.14,-0.5) sin(H);
    \filldraw [pattern=north east lines](D) cos (6.14,0.5) sin (F) cos (5.86,0.5) sin (D);
    \draw [style=dashed] (-2,0)--(6.5,0) (0,2)--(0,-2);
    %located zoomed figure
    \coordinate (zoomLoc) at (8,0);
    \spy [red,on background layer,
    spy connection path={\draw (tikzspyonnode) -- (tikzspyinnode);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426272/121799
    \begin{scope}[shift={(tikzspyinnode.south west)},x={($(tikzspyinnode.south east)-(tikzspyinnode.south west)$)},
    y={($(tikzspyinnode.north west)-(tikzspyinnode.south west)$)}]
     \draw[{Latex[open]}-,black,double=white] (0.15,0.75) -- ++ (0.5,0.5) -- ++ (0.5,0) 
     node[right,minimum size=0pt]{A};
     \draw[{Latex[open,fill=white]}-,black,double=white] (0.5,0.5) -- 
     ++ (0.35,0.35) -- ++ (0.35,0)  node[right,minimum size=0pt]{B};
     \draw[{Latex[open,fill=white]}-,black,double=white] (0.8,0.4) -- 
     ++ (0.25,-0.25) -- ++ (0.15,0)  node[right,minimum size=0pt]{C};
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}}] on (4,1.25) in node at (zoomLoc);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]